# jq - add parent key and move values into sub key

Tags: json, transform, jq

I'd like to add a parent key and move each value into a sub key.  For example, I want to convert the following json:

```
{                                                    
  "hello": "world",                                
  "foo": "bar"        
}
```

to

```
{
    "parent_key": {
        "hello": {
            "value": "world"
        },
        "foo": {
            "value": "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{ parent_key: map_values( {value: .}) }
```